# How to do conditional publishing?

Tags: php, publish, conditional-content, oop

I am trying to write a plugin that will stop a user from publishing (or updating) a post if a given condition is not met, for example, if the title of the post is already being used in a different post (I am using a custom post type, if that makes a difference).
I wrote a function that gets called through the 'transition_post_status' hook to attempt to catch the post before it gets published or updated in the database, so that I can stop that from happening.
When I test this out with a title I know I've already used I see the error message when the *wp_die()* function happens, so I know this function is getting called. However, the post is being created anyways. Is there something I'm missing? Is this even the best way of checking for conditions before letting a post be saved in the database?

This is what I have in the constructor:

```
add_action( 'transition_post_status', array( $this, 'post_publish_control' ), 10, 3 );
```

Later in the class:

```
public function post_publish_control( $new_status, $old_status, $post ) {

   // Make sure this function runs on correct post type
   if( $post->post_type === 'my_custom_post_type' ) {

      // On first-time publish or post update
      if( $new_status === 'publish' ) {

         // Try to catch an already existing title before post is saved
         if( does_post_title_exist( $post->post_title ) ) {
            wp_die( 'Title is already being used, try a different one.' );
         }
         // Continue if conditions are met
         else {
            return;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am a bit more used to object-oriented programming, so I'm trying to write this plugin as its own class.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the hook "transition_post_status" is called:

1. After the post has been published or updated in the database
2. After the status has been updated in the database.

Based on your problem statement, I believe the hook you want is "pre_post_update", as stated in [relevant WordPress source code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/post.php#L4194):

```
/**
 * Fires immediately before an existing post is updated in the database.
 *
 * @since 2.5.0
 *
 * @param int   $post_ID Post ID.
 * @param array $data    Array of unslashed post data.
 */
do_action( 'pre_post_update', $post_ID, $data );
```

This code is immediately followed by a call to `$wpdb->update( $wpdb->posts, $data, $where )`, which actually saves the post to the database.

**Usability issue**. I would advocate for not calling `wp_die()` if e.g. just the title is identical to one in the database. That's a bad user experience. It would make more sense to use a `add_filter` to rename the title if this happened:

```
/**
 * Filters slashed post data just before it is inserted into the database.
 *
 * @since 2.7.0
 *
 * @param array $data    An array of slashed post data.
 * @param array $postarr An array of sanitized, but otherwise unmodified post data.
 */
$data = apply_filters( 'wp_insert_post_data', $data, $postarr );
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on the hook, I didn't realize it happened after the database had been updated, but I'm not sure 'pre_post_update' is what I'm looking for since the docs say it happens before post update but not before post creation, which I also want to account for.
So far, I've been able to get around this issue with the 'wp_insert_post_data' filter you suggested (thanks for that also, by the way). Right now, that filter works on both post creation and update and it lets me change the post status to 'draft' so that the user can review it. Still working on the plugin!